# homework: Trying to sort out what operation I am attempting to compute C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, control-flow

Sorry for asking you guys and not my professor. (its due in a couple of hours and she is not available)
but I am just looking for a point in the right directions.

one piece of what I am writing tonight states two things...

```
Single-character versions of the C logical operators:

& for && (logical AND)
| for || (logical OR)
! for logical NOT
```

and this... as example output.

```
Enter an expression: (0 & 1) | (1 & 1)
Result: (0 & 1) | (1 & 1) = true
```

My pseudo logic is to take the input of '&' or '|'  and have it return as '&&' or '||' and throw it all back together based on the entered expression and let the program do the math.

But what I don't understand is what would make the above expression evaulwate to true? and or false? What should I research to lean more about the above expression? and what makes it true or false?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operators and `&&` and `||` are logical not same

Comment: Sounds like you may need to convert the expression to [postfix expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) if you need to handle any type of expression

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's just sudo code, lol

Comment: The expression evaluates to a number, that is interpreted as true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of `true` and `false` in C is of integers `0` for `false` and a non-zero number for `true`.

"single" boolean operators like `&`, `|`, `~` and `^` are called **bitwise** operators.

They work on two numbers, bit by bit - following the logic tables respectively - AND, OR, ONE-COMPLEMENT(not) and XOR.

So, your expression:

`(0 & 1) | (1 & 1)` is true because `0 & 1` = `0`, `1 & 1` = `1` and `0 | 1` is `1`. which is true.

What could turn this into `false` is if the expression was combined with an `&` instead of `|` like so:

`(0 & 1) & (1 & 1)` = `false`.

Truth table of AND:

```
+---------------+---------+
|  A    +   B   |   A & B |
+---------------+---------+
| 0     |   0   |    0    |
| 0     |   1   |    0    | 
| 1     |   0   |    0    |
| 1     |   1   |    1    |
+---------------+---------+
```

Truth table of OR:

```
+---------------+---------+
|  A    +   B   |   A | B |
+---------------+---------+
| 0     |   0   |    0    |
| 0     |   1   |    1    | 
| 1     |   0   |    1    |
| 1     |   1   |    1    |
+---------------+---------+
```

---

However, since C99, `true` and `false` are reserved words, and will evaluate to `0` and `1` internally - The answer posted above applies for C99 as well as C89

Comment: your answer is a bit misleading. Your first setence is correct for the thruth values "false" and "true", but not for the reserved identifiers `false` and `true`, in particular for `true`. Since C99, this is supposed to be a macro that evaluates to `1`.

Comment: @JensGustedt you are right - I must clarify this in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way:

```
(0 & 1) | (1 & 1)

= (0 and 1) or (1 and 1)

= (false and true) or (true and true)

= (false) or (true)

= true
```

[Further reading at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone's input. Really helped.

```
int logicalCheck (int a, int x, int b) {

// let 88 = true
//  let 89 = false

if (x == '&') {
    if (a == b) {
        return 88;
    }
    if (a != b) {
        return 89;
    }

}

if (x == '|') {
    if ((a == b && a) || b != 0) {
        return 88;
    }
    if (a || b == 0) {
        return 89;
    }

}

return 0;
```

Comment: Your result is incorrect. It would resolve to 0 & 0 being 1. Actually it is even worse and entirely incorrect. It would only work with the given example and that is just an example. Your professor will use different values for the actual test and you will need to get the entire boolean logic correct. Additionally, you entirely missed the ! (not).